# Unable to create regular expression for diffrent URL's

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and want to create a regular expression which can capture both the urls's below:

I am trying using this expression:

```
movies/(.+?)/(.+?)&amp
```

Its not working for both the url's:

```
https://in.bookmyshow.com/bengaluru/movies/avengers-endgame/ET00090482&amp;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/movies/the-tashkent-files/ET00069063/&amp;
```

Comment: Hi Emma, i want to create a regular expression which captures both the url. I am running 2 iteration with different movie names. My test is failing because my expression doesn't capture both values... I want to extract avengers-endgame/ET00090482 only, Means name of the movie and ID

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we might to pass a domain and capture a few components of the URLs here such as the ID. Let's begin with an expression with more boundaries, then we will remove them, if undesired:

```
(.+?)(in.bookmyshow.com)\/(.+?)\/([A-Z0-9]+)(.*&amp;)
```

[image]

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yUhXY8/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yUhXY8/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

#### Demo

This snippet is just to show that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /(.+?)(in.bookmyshow.com)\/(.+?)\/([A-Z0-9]+)(.*&amp;)/gm;
const str = `https://in.bookmyshow.com/bengaluru/movies/avengers-endgame/ET00090482&amp;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/movies/the-tashkent-files/ET00069063/&amp;`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

If we wish to pass URLs that have `movies` and fail those without it, we can add a new boundary to our initial expression:

```
(.+?)(in.bookmyshow.com)\/(.+)?movies(.+)?\/([A-Z0-9]+)(.*&amp;)
```

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GNKzS2/1)

```js
const regex = /(.+?)(in.bookmyshow.com)\/(.+)?movies(.+)?\/([A-Z0-9]+)(.*&amp;)/gm;
const str = `https://in.bookmyshow.com/bengaluru/movies/avengers-endgame/ET00090482&amp;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/movies/the-tashkent-files/ET00069063/&amp;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/music/the-tashkent-files/ET00069063/&amp;
https://in.bookmyshow.com/bengaluru/music/the-tashkent-files/ET00069063/&amp;`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but wanted to add on to what Emma posted.

Once you get your groupings how you want, in JMeter there is a field for "Match No.".  If you put

```
refName_n_g<group number>
```

it should return the piece you want.  So if the movie title in the regex is group 2 you'd put

```
refName_n_g2
```

Here's a page on JMeter and regex:

[Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Edit:
using

```
movies\/(.+?\/.+?)&amp
```

your group 1 would give you "avengers-endgame/ET00090482"

Answer (score 0):

Your expression: movies/(.+?)/(.+?)&amp

Since you searching 2 groups: Movie name(avengers-endgame) and ID(ET00090482), you need to take the **template as $1$$2$** in Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter

Also, please check the sections - **Apply to** and **Fields to check** to be selected as per the requirement

[image]

Reference:

[How to use Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://youtu.be/gOGXMa08K3s?list=PLkkGqdBS1r094KcNXRy4Q-v5biuNWv-h7&t=1025)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regular expression and let me know the results.

movies/(.*?)&

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Did you test the expression? Do you expect it to work? Or you just posted a homework / quiz for the OP?

Comment: As per his question, he wanted to fetch the below values from both the URLs

/avengers-endgame/ET00090482
/the-tashkent-files/ET00069063/

I have tested my regular expression and it works fine.
The regular expression created by him i.e. "movies/(.+?)/(.+?)&amp" is also good. it just needs a little update. It should be "movies/(.+?)/(.+?)&"

Why he is facing this problem? 
It seems that he has right clicked on the page and click view page source which encodes special characters ( & is converted into &amp;) and tried to create regular expression.

Comment: I have added some screenshots as well so that you should be able to understand it properly.